# Not getting any rows from query but there are rows available in the table

Tags: sql-server

```
AND (
    (datediff(DAY,getdate(), '2020-07-14 00:00:00.000') = 5)
    OR (
        datediff(DAY,getdate(), A.HX_RELIEVING_DT) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
        AND '2020-04-17 20:36:53.000' >= GETDATE()-1
    )
)
```

This is the output I want for relieving date and last updated time but I am unable to get this

```
 EMPLID LOCATION    SUPERVISOR_ID    HX_RELIEVING_DT               LASTUPDDTTM
 -- SINGAPORE          ---        2020-07-14 00:00:00.000       2020-04-17 20:36:53.000
```

Comment: You have to pass GETDATE() in the third part of DATEDIFF function

Comment: what is this "AND '2020-04-17 20:36:53.000' >= GETDATE()-1 " are you trying to decrease date. you should use DATEADD.

Comment: @Dale K i am using sql server but it is general query so tagged my-sql

Comment: Please check the official docs, [datediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [dateadd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: MySQL is a specific database product - not a general SQL tag... please remove it.

Comment: Please show the sample data which should produce the shown result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you tried to write if @MyDate is past:

```
 AND ((DATEDIFF(DAY, @MyDate, GETDATE()) = 5) OR (DATEDIFF( DAY, A.HX_RELIEVING_DT, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 4 AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) <= @MyDate))
```

If @MyDate is future:

```
 AND ((DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), @MyDate) = 5) OR (DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), A.HX_RELIEVING_DT) BETWEEN 0 AND 4 AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) <= @MyDate))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @iman tried with above solution but not getting the output which i have shown...AND ((DATEDIFF(DAY, A.HX_RELIEVING_DT, GETDATE()) = 5) OR (DATEDIFF( DAY, A.HX_RELIEVING_DT, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 4 AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) >= A.LASTUPDDTTM))

Comment: Omar as Dale said you have to read about  DATEDIFF and DATEADD. Then try to fix your query. Or please explain more about details in the Query. as you see ''2020-07-14 00:00:00.000' is the near future. so maybe your first version was right.

Answer (score 0):

Last condition from your WHERE clause is basically filtering your record from the output.

```
AND '2020-04-17 20:36:53.000' >= GETDATE()-1
```

A date from month "April" can not be bigger than a date value from July, right? You can check the values you are using in different condition in WHERE clause with this below query. You will get your issue automatically.

```
SELECT *,
datediff(DAY,getdate(), '2020-07-14 00:00:00.000'),
datediff(DAY,getdate(), A.HX_RELIEVING_DT),
GETDATE()-1
FROM your_table A
```